# TYPO3 parseFunc.short in html tags

Tags: tags, typo3, typoscript

everybody

I'm using TYPO3 (4.5.17). 
In my content, I have some specific tags that I would like to replace

For example:
I'd like to transform this

```
....<intertitre>Mon titre de section</intertitre>...
```

to

```
....<h2>Mon titre de section</h2>...
```

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
page.stdWrap.parseFunc.short {
  intertitre = h3
}
```

Someone can help me, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the definition to lib.parseFunc (non-RTE fields) and lib.parseFunc_RTE (RTE fields). So every field which uses that definition will work. Means: if you can use f.e. strong, you will be able to use your own tag:

```
lib.parseFunc.short {
  intertitre = h3
}
lib.parseFunc_RTE.short < lib.parseFunc.short
```

AFAIK the page Object does not have stdWrap functionality.